# jQuery.html issue and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Whenever I use .html withing a jQuery function such as jQuery.ajax it appends in Interent Explorer.  Anybody knows what could be causing this?

```
<script language="javascript">
    /*
    jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test</b>');
    jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test2</b>');
    */
</script>
```

OUTPUT: test 2

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test</b>');
        jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test2</b>');
    });
</script>
```

OUTPUT: test test2

Comment: Can you post the contents of `#data-grid`?  Also, is there a reason that the first script is commented out?

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?  Can you reproduce this in a simple page and show us?

Comment: if you send more details, and complete page code, may be we can give better answers

Comment: Do you have multiple `id="data-grid"` elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote:

```
jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test</b>');
jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test2</b>');
```

Anywhere the output should be:

**test2** in the data-grid element.

because [.html() function](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) is not appending values.

Answer (score 0):

it should be test2 but in internet explorere if I write

```
   jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test</b>');
        jQuery("#data-grid").html('<b>test2</b>');
    });
```

The output is **test test2** The reason I'm wrapping this in a function is to illustrate that if I have a an ajax call like:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: file,
        data: params_string,
        timeout: 20000,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            AJAX_error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(html){
            jQuery("#data-grid").html(html);
            AJAX_success();

        }
    });
```

Lets assume that first AJAX call returns "test" and second "test2".  Instead of replacing the content of #data-grid. It appends to it.  The ajax call is being called onclick event.